# Regex to find complete words at Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to only get the records that have some words at one column, I have tried using `WHERE ... IN (...)` but Postgres is case sensitive in this where clause.
This is why I tried regex and `~*` operator.

The following is a SQL snippet that returns all the columns and tables from the DB, I want to restrict the rows to bring only the tables in the regex expresion.

```
SELECT ordinal_position as COLUMN_ID, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
                        FROM information_schema.columns
                        WHERE table_schema = 'public' and  table_name ~* 'PRODUCTS|BALANCES|BALANCESBARCODEFORMATS|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIES|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIESSUB'
                        order by TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_ID
```

This regex will bring all the columns of BALANCES and the columns of the tables that contain the 'BALANCES' keyword.

I want to restrict the result to complete names only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using regexes, the common solution is using [***word boundaries***](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) before and after the current expression.

See effect without: http://regexr.com?35ecl

See effect with word boundaries: http://regexr.com?35eci

In PostgreSQL, [the word boundaries are denoted by `\y`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE) <sup>(other popular regex engines, such as PCRE, C# and Java, use `\b` instead - thus its use in the regex demo above - thanks [@IgorRomanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818688/igor-romanchenko))</sup>.

Thus, for your case, the expression below could be used <sup>(the matches are the same as the example regexes in the links above)</sup>:

```
'\y(PRODUCTS|BALANCES|BALANCESBARCODEFORMATS|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIES|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIESSUB)\y'
```

See demo of this expression in use here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/9f597/1

Comment: In Postgres `\b` means `backspace, as in C`. You can use `\y` for `matches only at the beginning or end of a word`. Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: Pedantic, but I'd say "many other regex engines" rather than "usual regexes" - regexes are not really standardised, so it's usually best to find the manual for whatever "flavour" a particular tool runs rather than making any assumptions.

Comment: @IMSoP Agreed. Changed that description. PostgreSQL is not alone in the use of `\y`. There are some tools that use is as well, as noted in the link about ***[word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)*** I used.

Comment: marked as the correct answer because you are burned out and provided with all these usefull links :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match only whole `table_name` use something like

```
'^(PRODUCTS|BALANCES|BALANCESBARCODEFORMATS|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIES|BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIESSUB)$'
```

`^` matches at the beginning of the string.

`$` matches at the end of the string.

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html).

Alternatively you can  use something like:

```
 upper(table_name) IN ('PRODUCTS','BALANCES','BALANCESBARCODEFORMATS','BALANCESEXPORTCATEGORIES', ...)
```

to make `IN` case insensitive.